# Rewriting resource model for admin

Tags: module, overrides, resource-model

I need to modify the `_beforeSave` function of `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer` i created a new file in my module with the new method and put the rewrite in my `config.xml`

```
    <models>
        <customer_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <customer>Name_Module_Model_Resource_Customer</customer>
            </rewrite>
        </customer_resource>
    </models>
```

the new method works on the frontend (register page) but when I try to save a customer in admin it uses the core method what do I need to do to tell the admin about the rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the method from the original class, this line `parent::_beforeSave($customer);` will call the original method.
I replaced that line with

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave($customer);`
and it works!